# arranging an elements of a tuple to only print a part of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi the code down below prints all the valid combinations for 3 sets of lists within a range. I am trying to set all the list values down below to 1 decimal place however its not working and also I am trying to print out each parts of the `list_set` by itself. so instead of the results being `(0.0, 1, 1) (0.0, 1, 2) (0.0, 2, 1) (0.0, 2, 2) (0.1, 1, 1) (0.1, 1, 2) (0.1, 2, 1) (0.1, 2, 2)` I want the results to print set1`(0.0) (0.0) (0.0) (0.0) (0.1) (0.1) (0.1) (0.1)`

```
import itertools

set1 = [x * 0.1 for x in range(0, 100)]
set2 = [i for i in range(1,3)]
set3 = [i for i in range(1,3)]
            
list_set = [set1, set2, set3]
for element in itertools.product(*list_set):
  print(element)
```

Comment: can you explain you're desired output better?

Comment: When you run this code it prints out `[set1, set2, set3]`  however I also want to get the individual parts of the code by itself `set2` or `set1`

Comment: what does ```itertools.product(*list_set)``` do

Comment: the code prints every possible combination not ```[set1, set2, set3]``` ?

Comment: `itertool.product()` pretty much goes through all the possible combinations for all 3 sets. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: exactly so how do you know which belongs to ```set1``` ```set2``` or ```set3```

Comment: set1 set2 and set3 are defined above and are listed in order in list_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers your first part, using `round(value, decimal_place)`

```
set1 = [round(x * 0.1,1) for x in range(0, 100)]
set2 = [round(i,1) for i in range(1, 3)]
set3 = [round(i,1) for i in range(1, 3)]

list_set = [set1, set2, set3]
for element in itertools.product(*list_set):
    print(element[0])
```

use `element[0]` to access the `set1`

I don't understand why you need `itertools`
You can just do this as well

```
for element in set1:
    print(element)
```

Comment: Thank you the rounding works in the section                                                                           `list_set = [set1, set2, set3]
for element in itertools.product(*list_set):
  print(element)`                                                                                                                                         I want to print the parts of the list_set instead of it printing the whole thing. Like i want to print only the `set1` part of `list_set` so instead of the result being `(0.0, 1, 1)` it would only be `(0.0)`

Comment: i've edited my answer, but if that is what you want cant you just print ```set1``` on its own without ```itertools```

Comment: Thank you that was all I needed